# How to Identify an annular region in a very low contrast image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[What procedure should be followed to identify the **annular region**(pinkish orange color) having a white background. Also how to **amplify the intensity** values in the annular region to further work on them.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I can't see anything.

Comment: @AnderBiguri very light pink circle is present with its center at the center of the image. A close look is required. This is to be identified using MATLAB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as ease of processing, your best bet is going to be to convert your image to an alternate colorspace. Personally, I would convert [to HSV and use the saturation channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wJpd.jpg');
hsv = rgb2hsv(img);

saturation = hsv(:,:,2);

figure;
imshow(saturation);
```

[image]

Then you could do all sorts of filtering/processing to extract the annulus in the image. One potential method is shown below but there are a huge number of ways to process this data.

```
% Apply a median filter to remove random false positives
M = medfilt2(saturation < 0.4, [13 13]);

% Label each connected component
L = bwlabel(~M);

% Find the biggest connected component
L = L == mode(L(L > 0));

% Segment it and fill the center hole
filled = imfill(L, 'holes');

% Show the result
figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(L)
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(filled)
```

[image]

Comment: Was about to do this. But you are faster ! :P Good one

Comment: Nicely done. Good work in using the saturation channel.